# MATLAB 4 decimal point precision calculation

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, is there any way at all to make it do all calculations using only 4 digits after decimal ?
If I write fprintf('%85.83f\n',single(1.1566)), its not exactly 1.1566. For my specific problem I cannot afford to accumulate those extra digits.
I want all internal calculations to be done on this precision only.

Comment: What do you mean by 'cannot afford to accumulate those extra digits'? Do you mean it is too slow to compute?

Comment: By 'cannot afford', I mean that my model accumulates these errors gradually and summed error increases.

Answer (score 1):

By default MATLAB conducts all operations with double precision. If you want your operations to use a lower precision, you can use [`variable precision arithmetic`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/f1-5556.html), which is part of the Symbolic Math Toolbox. In your case, first set the precision to 4 significant  digits using the [`digits`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/digits.html) function, and then declare and manipulate variables using the [`vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/vpa.html) function:

```
old_precision = digits; % Save the old precision
digits(4);
vpa(1/3 + 1/2)
digits(old_precision); % Set the precision back
```

will output

```
>> vpa(1/3+1/2)

ans =

0.8333
```

Another example:

```
>> digits(3);
>> a = 5.4;
>> vpa(a)+1/3

ans =

5.73
```

Comment: Well, the problem with VPA is I just cannot keep on using symbolic elements to represent my entire system.
I am looking for something more like the data class single; but lesser precision.
As pointed out, I think my only options are to change my system to bear these errors or make it correct upto the decimal precision of the single data class.

Answer (score 1):

The MathWorks offer a [Fixed-Point Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/fixedpoint/)  which might meet OP's needs.

However, if OP's statement *I cannot afford to accumulate those extra digits* is code for *I want faster execution and don't mind the loss of precision* I fear that OP may be out of luck.  On modern digital computers with either 32- or 64-bit (or both) floating-point computations built into the hardware, computations at a non-hardware-precision will have to be done in software and are likely to be noticeably slower.

Comment: I am looking for something like the single data class not symbolic objects.
Its not speed thats the problem; I think changing my system will be the best solution.
Thanks anyways !